# Interactive 3D model in flash export data to php

Tags: php, flash, 3d, unity-game-engine

Do flash 3D display engines such as Papervision allow data to be exported from the swf to a php back end and vice versa (PHP into model)? Does Unity allow for this?

If I was to build a simple 'change the colour of the model' application with a UI in a 3D package such as Papervision, could I then export the user choices to php or perhaps a javascript intermediary?

Thanks for any help
MitchK

Answer (score 2):

It is up to you to define what informations the user can export or not , just like when you code a formular in html, Flash can send GET / POST requests to a server , you can send whatever datas you want back to the server.

Comment: Thanks. I'm quite experienced in transeferring data from flash, but if the 3D model and UI is designed in a package such as papervision, can this data be exported? Or, another way, if I have a 3D object in papervision, can I change colours, update the model etc from the wrapper flash?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to. Here's a trivial old example on how to export a mesh from Papervision to the [Collada](https://collada.org/mediawiki/index.php/COLLADA_-_Digital_Asset_and_FX_Exchange_Schema) format:

```
package {
    import flash.net.FileReference;
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import org.papervision3d.core.io.exporters.ExportCollada;
    import org.papervision3d.lights.PointLight3D;
    import org.papervision3d.view.BasicView;
    import org.papervision3d.materials.shadematerials.FlatShadeMaterial;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.DisplayObject3D;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.primitives.PaperPlane;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.special.UCS;

    public class PV3DExportTest extends BasicView {
        private var mesh:DisplayObject3D;
        public function PV3DExportTest()  {
            super(640,480,false,false,"Debug");
            scene.addChild(new UCS(1000));
            var light:PointLight3D = scene.addChild(new PointLight3D()) as PointLight3D; light.x = light.y = light.z = 100;
            mesh = scene.addChild(new PaperPlane(new FlatShadeMaterial(light,0xFFFF00,0xFF6600),3));mesh.rotationY = 160;mesh.rotationX = 30;
            startRendering();
            stage.doubleClickEnabled = true;
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK,save);
        }
        private function save(event:MouseEvent):void{
            var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            data.writeUTFBytes(ExportCollada.export(mesh));
            new FileReference().save(data,'mesh.dae');
        }
    }
}
```

you can see it running [here](http://wonderfl.net/c/e9LI).

You will need to check if the library you are going to use already exports to a 3D file format that can preserve the data you need (colours/materials/etc.) and if not implement your own. Once that's done, the data transfer should be trivial. There are q few options, so it's up to your setup what method suits you best.

Comment: That's a basic example with Papervision(which is old/dormant project). Away3D also provides exporters, like the [OBJ](http://away3d.com/livedocs/3.6.0_lib/away3d/exporters/ObjExporter.html) one. Still, these are ASCII/text based formats. The advantage is you can open them in a text editor or import them them in a 3D editor, but the disadvantage is filesize. If that's an issue you can either make up a binary format or write an exporter for an existing one (like .3ds) which could be stored as a blob in MySQL. Binary is also faster to parse. HTH